# This year's festival will end with a display of fireworks being set off at midnight

Tags: grammar, sentence

May I ask you to help me with this issue?

Have got the following sentence:

- This year's festival will end with a display of fireworks *to be set off at midnight.*

Would it be possible to change this sentence to:

- This year's festival will end with a display of fireworks *being set off at midnight.*

If so, what would be the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: You could put *"This year's festival will end with a firework display at midnight"*.

Answer (score 1):

"...to be set off" works better with "festival includes" than festival "will end with". (I think it has something to do with the passive voice, but I'm not sure.)

For the picture it creates in the mind, I think that "being set off" is the better of the two if you want to attract people to the show.

Weather Vane's "end with a fireworks display at midnight" would be more succinct.